# how to get java class object values in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a java class **Main.java** where I'm calculating the Sum and Difference in the variable like

```
int sum = a+b;
int diff = a-b;
```

`a` and `b` are are the values which are coming from the database through Hibernate.
now i want to Display the sum and diff values on a JSP. please Help me out to bring sum and diff values from java class **Main.java** to jsp. Please give sum Example code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate your Main.java in Servlet / JSP

place it in a scope: `session` or `request`

```
like request.setAttribute("myMain",main);
```

access in jsp usinh

```
Main myMain = (Main)request.getAttribute("myMain");

myMain.getSum()
```

Comment: And importing the class: `<%@page import="org.saurabh.calc.Main" %>`.

Comment: I tried but I'm facing Problem Look I hav Class Main.java then I have Public Ststic void main Method inside it. then inside that method i have values of sum and diff. now I have tried your code but the time i right myMain.getmain() it is throughing me an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the JSTL route use

```
<c:out value="${myMain.sum}"/>
```